# Why can't linux password start with '#'

Tags: linux, password, login

My password for temporary things and testing was something like:

> #password123

On Windows everything worked fine, but when I started working with Linux distros (tested at least on CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu), after setting any password that started with '#' I simply couldn't log in any more.

What really happens behind the scenes to prevent having this kind of password?

My first idea was '#' is ussualy comment, it comments what follows, but everything is hashed and salted which immediately rejects my idea.

Comment: Are you sure you used the same keyboard layout when setting and entering  the password?

Comment: Thought of that and yes. Besides # is typed the same way on my layout as  on the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can.

```
[root@risby yum]# echo "#foot" | passwd --stdin guest
Changing password for user guest.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.

[me@risby ~]$ ssh guest@localhost
Password: (typed #foot)
Last login: Thu Dec  3 09:16:06 2015 from ::1
[guest@risby ~]$
```

So I fear your question is founded on a wrong assumption.  It might be better to open a new question, **showing** us what you're doing, and the results that you think are anomalous.  But there is clearly no *fundamental* bar on passwords starting with a hash symbol.  The test above was carried out on a Fedora 22 system, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Tested your way and it works. If think back, I've always set my password during OS installation. Will test it again and hopefully I can reproduce the issue, otherwise I'll just go sit in the corner and cry. Marked as the answer for my not enough specific answer. Thanks!